# How to pull items from a collection using meteor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, meteor, angular-meteor

I'm new to meteor and I'm trying to run the very beginners tutorial and I'm having troubles reading data from a collection.

Here's my js

```
import angular from 'angular';
import angularMeteor from 'angular-meteor';
import { Tasks } from '../../api/tasks.js';
import template from './todosList.html';

class TodosListCtrl {
  constructor($scope) {
    $scope.viewModel(this);

    this.helpers({
      tasks() {
        return Tasks.find();
      }
    })
  }
}

export default angular.module('todosList', [
  angularMeteor
])
  .component('todosList', {
    templateUrl: 'imports/components/todosList/todosList.html',
    controller: TodosListCtrl
  });
```

and I have declared my collection like this (imports/api/tasks.js):

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, will accept any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to be able to access the scope. in your component, you shoud have `controller: ['$scope', TodosListCtrl]`

Then if you insert a new task, you will see it `db.tasks.insert({ text: "Hello world!", createdAt: new Date() });`